# Placing caption on a separate page

Tags: floats, captions

I got back the correction for my M.Sc thesis (breast cancer). The corrector want the caption of landscale graphics to be on the next page. Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Load math package
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Set up the headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
%Allows first indent and loads setspace package to be used in different documents.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}

%Make cell space and scientific notation
\usepackage{longtable, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}


%Enables paragraph spacing. Saves the old indent value and restores it after loading the parskip package. Otherwise, you lose the indents. 
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=apa,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Chapters/references.bib}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
This figure illustrates the wide peak boundaries most likely to contain the targeted genes. 
Regions are mapped onto the mm9 mouse genome. Recall that these regions have a FQR < 0.25. There are 44 amplified regions, 109 deleted regions, and 17 regions are both amplified and deleted in different tumour subsets. Importantly, there are clear arm-length deletions, namely 15p, 21p, and 22p. More than 50\% of 18q is split into two close regions. There is a series of centromeric and para-centromeric deletions on chromosome 9. There is no arm-length amplification.
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.90\linewidth]{Figure6.png}
\caption[Statistically significant chromosomal aberrations]{\textbf{Statistically significant chromosomal aberrations.} There are 44 amplified regions, 109 deleted regions, and 16 regions that are both amplified and deleted in different tumour subsets. Particularly, there are 3 single arm-length deletions, namely 15p, 21p, and 22p. Additionally, more than 50\% of 18q is fragmented into close regions. There is no arm-length amplification. Regions are mapped onto the hg18 human genome.}
\label{fig:regions}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here is the picture in the same path of main.tex:

[image]

If you run the example, you will get some text on the first page, and the landscape picture on the second page with a text caption with a bold title: "Figure 1: Statistically significant chromosomal aberrations. ..."

Essentially, I need the text caption/box aligned in the middle on a third page. Is there a simple way of doing so? Thank you!

Comment: Please split the question into two separate questions. Providing a minimal working example will lead to faster and better results.

Comment: In addition, neither question is particularly clear (especially the second one). When you say the caption needs to be on a separate page, where should it appear? At the bottom? At the top? In the middle? With a pointer to the next page?  How is one to know what the caption refers to?  For the second question, you give `.bib` items, but the problem is with the formatting of them, so the `.bib` items don't themselves help. What's needed is the bibliography package (`natbib`? `biblatex`?) you are using, and the bibliography style that you are loading, and then what exactly the requirement is.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi! Thank you for your response. The caption is the picture's description. When you look at a picture in a textbook, you will most often see a small description right under like : "Figure 2. This pictures shows...."

Comment: @Johnathan I'm well aware of what a caption is, but your requirement seems to say that it should be "on a separate page", which is not the same as "right under" (which is why we are asking you to clarify your question(s).  So do two things: edit this question, remove your bibliography question and make it clear (with a minimal document) what you want to do with the caption. Then make a second question which also has a minimal document (with the relevant bibliography packages) but shows instead just the bibliography trouble you are having.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi! So, I removed my bibliography question and made a minimal document. Is that ok? One can save the image in the same directory and run the main.tex file.

Comment: @Johnathan Thanks!  Much clearer now. (Very odd requirement for a one-sided document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a regular `\caption` use the `\captionof` facility of the `caption` package. Remove the caption from your figure environment, and then after your figure put:

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\captionof{figure}[Statistically significant chromosomal aberrations]{\textbf{Statistically significant chromosomal aberrations.} There are 44
amplified regions, 109 deleted regions, and 16 regions that are both 
amplified and deleted in different tumour subsets. Particularly, there are 
3 single arm-length deletions, namely 15p, 21p, and 22p. Additionally, more 
than 50\% of 18q is fragmented into close regions. There is no arm-length 
amplification. Regions are mapped onto the hg18 human genome.}
\label{fig:regions}
\vspace{\fill}
\clearpage
```

Comment: Not only with `caption` package, but also with KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: Or use two figures, one without a caption and one consisting of just a caption .

Comment: @Alan Munn Hi! I am trying to do a similar thing with text, but latex doesn't number the table properly. Could you please look at it?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261829/i-am-trying-to-number-the-table-properly-but-latex-doesnt-seem-to-recognize-the
Thank you!